# How does one gain reputation on Stack Exchange and similar sites?

Tags: discussion

If one knows hardly anything and thus cannot answer others' questions, how can one gain reputation? I am new and it seems all of the questions are too advanced for me to answer. Edit: The link you posted to show me that this is a duplicate still doesn't answer my question. It says "ask good questions and provide good answers." This is not something that I can do when I don't know what the hell I'm doing yet...

Comment: You gain reputation by asking good questions and answering questions. See our [tour] and our [ask] and [answer] pages. Also, read our Help Center article on [Reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I think reputation is partly intended to measure how much expertise you have (although it is a poor measure - it more accurately reflects time spent), so if you don't know anything, better... learn some stuff. Also, gaining reputation is a sort of nice reward for contributing great content and thus helping many people now and in the future; gaining reputation is hopefully not your actual goal...

Comment: In response to your edit, like I said before, if you don't know what the hell you're doing yet, why do you think you should be able to get reputation? It would defy the purpose of reputation if it were easy to get it while being totally clueless about the site topic, don't you think?

Comment: Sure. But then you can't comment on questions to request clarification, and thus you can't get your question answered, and you can't learn. The cycle repeats.

Answer (score 0):

As you learn more, you will become more advanced and be able to answer more advanced questions. But first I recommend learning how the site works. Because this is not the place to ask this question. Ask Ubuntu is purely questions about Ubuntu. But the you can ask these sorts of questions in the Ask Ubuntu Meta forums. Or any Meta forum really.